# R Shiny: sqldf not work with observe, shows: Error in result_create: near "&": syntax error

Tags: r, shiny, sqldf

I'm trying to let the choropleth map to react while user change inputs using slider. I'm using sqldf library to query the result and plot it in the map. However, currently, I'm getting the result of "Error in result_create: near "&": syntax error". Not sure how to fix it or maybe I was wrong from the beginning.

```
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(evaluate)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(sf)
library(geojsonio)
library(sqldf)
library(DBI)
library(gsubfn)
library(RH2)
library(RSQLite)
library(rJava)
library(shinydashboard)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
   # Application title
   dashboardHeader(title="Vic Car Accidents"),
   dashboardSidebar(
     sliderInput("range", "Year:",
                 min = 2013, max = 2018,
                 value = c(2013,2018))),

   dashboardBody(
            box(title = "Choropleth Map",width = 12, status = "primary",leafletOutput("young_driver",width = "100%", height = 400)
                ),
            box(tableOutput("values"))
   ))


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
options(scipen = 999)
#read LGA geojson file from local file
LGA<-st_read("Data/LGA.geojson",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#read car crashes data from local file
carCrashes<- read_csv("Data/Car.csv")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    data.frame(name = "range", value= (paste(input$range[1],input$range[2])))})
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })

  temp <- observe({
    year_1 <- input$range[1]
    year_2 <- input$range[2]
    #data.frame(name = "range", value= (paste(input$range[1],input$range[2])))})
    read.csv.sql(
    "Data/Car.csv",
    sql = ("select distinct LGA_NAME, count(LGA_NAME) as 'number of young driver'
    from file
    where driver_type = 'young driver' and
year_period >= year_1 && year_period <= year_2
    group by LGA_NAME; ")

  )
    sub_and_car <- left_join(LGA,temp,by = c("VIC_LGA__3" = "LGA_NAME"))
    output$young_driver<-renderLeaflet({

      tm<-tm_shape(sub_and_car)+tm_polygons(col="number of young driver", border.col="grey")

      tmap_leaflet(tm)
    })


 # output$young_driver<-renderLeaflet({



  # tm<-tm_shape(sub_and_car)+tm_polygons(col="number of young driver", border.col="grey")

  #tmap_leaflet(tm)
  })
   })


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: no way to reproduce it without any data.

Comment: There are two datasets that I'm using. One is geojson data with local government name, another is car accidents records having each accident's locations( same to local government name). Here is the repository https://github.com/lkjcbl/R-project

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it... you made multiple mistakes in your code:

`observeEvent` should only be used for check for sideeffekts never to create a data.frame. Always use `eventReactive` to do that. There were many bugs I could not figure out in your `sqldf` code. I anyway recommend learning `dplyr`,it´s the standard others programmers also use.

Seperate creating `data.frames` from rendering Widgets. Since the Map takes long time to render, I used `shinycssloaders` to show the user some feedback. Otherwise he or she may just close the App.

Here is the Code, just change the paths:

```
library(magrittr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(evaluate)
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(sf)
library(geojsonio)
library(sqldf)
library(DBI)
library(gsubfn)
library(RH2)
library(RSQLite)
library(rJava)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
   # Application title
   dashboardHeader(title="Vic Car Accidents"),
   dashboardSidebar(
     sliderInput("range", "Year:",
                 min = 2013, max = 2018,
                 value = c(2013,2018)),
   actionButton("change", "Change")),

   dashboardBody(
            box(title = "Choropleth Map",width = 12, status = "primary",withSpinner(leafletOutput("young_driver",width = "100%", height = 400))
                ),
            box(tableOutput("values"))
   ))


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
options(scipen = 999)
#read LGA geojson file from local file
LGA<-st_read("C:/Users/User/Downloads/R-project-master/R-project-master/LGA.geojson",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#read car crashes data from local file
carCrashes<- read_csv("C:/Users/User/Downloads/R-project-master/R-project-master/Car.csv")

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    data.frame(name = "range", value= (paste(input$range[1],input$range[2])))})
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })

  cmap <- eventReactive(input$change,{
    range_1 <- as.numeric(input$range[1])
    range_2 <- as.numeric(input$range[2])

    temp <- carCrashes %>%
      filter(driver_type == 'young driver' & year_period >= range_1 & year_period <= range_2) %>%
      group_by(LGA_NAME) %>%
      mutate(`Number of young drivers` = n())


    # temp<- sqldf(
    # "C:/Users/User/Downloads/R-project-master/R-project-master/Car.csv",
    # sql = paste("select distinct LGA_NAME, count(LGA_NAME) as 'number of young driver' 
    # from file
    # where driver_type = 'young driver' and
    # year_period between range_1 and range_2
    # group by LGA_NAME; ")

    sub_and_car <- left_join(LGA,temp,by = c("VIC_LGA__3" = "LGA_NAME"))

    })

  output$young_driver <- renderLeaflet({
    tm <- tm_shape(cmap())+tm_polygons(col="Number of young drivers", border.col="grey")
    tmap_leaflet(tm)
  })

   })


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! Just wondering if there is any way to improve the rendering time?

Comment: yes of couse => join the data ONCE at the beginning, not every time you make a userinput. If my answer was helpful, please accept it :-)